# PHP remove newline in string inside HTML tag

Tags: php, regex

I'm not good at regex and I need a quick answer for solving this problem. How to remove newline in string inside HTML tag using PHP, something like this:

input:

```
<li>first line</li>
<li>second 
line</li>
<li>third 
line and 
the last</li>
```

output:

```
<li>first line</li>
<li>second line</li>
<li>third line and the last</li>
```

What i've tried so far without any success:

```
<?php
preg_match('/<li><\/li>/')
preg_replace('/<li>\n+<\/li>/', '', $string)
```

Comment: Why quick? Can we see what you have tried so far? Any code?

Comment: I tried to find the tag with `preg_match('/<li><\/li>/')`, then i don't know the step after this.

Comment: Preg_match simply returns a bool value if it finds or doesn't find the reg expression.  Use preg_replace and specify an empty string to replace occurrences of it.  That's the case in general at least, I don't think reg expressions are what you want in this scenario though.  At the bare minimum, you can replace '\n' but it might depend on the situation.

Comment: I tried that too, `preg_replace('/<li>\n+<\/li>/', '', $string)`, nothing happend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not so good with Regex, but this is what I made:

```
<?php
$string = '<li>first line</li>
<li>second 
line</li>
<li>third 
line and 
the last</li>';

// Fetch each <li> element
$new_string = preg_replace_callback ( '/<li>(.*?)<\\/li>/mis', function ( $aMatches ) {
    // Replace enters within <li> and </li>
    return preg_replace ( '/[\\r\\n]/', '', $aMatches[0] );
}, $string);

echo $new_string;
```

Which results in:

```
<li>first line</li>
<li>second line</li>
<li>third line and the last</li>
```

Comment: Thank you, i'm working on too, the idea is the same.  Find the string enclosed the tag, remove the newline and repeat each tag. That `preg_replace_callback` save me.

Comment: I'm sure there is a better way, but this is what I came up with. Glad to help you! Have fun coding!

Comment: By the way, 1 more question. What is  `mis` in `/<li>(.*?)<\\/li>/mis` used for?

Comment: `m` = treat as multi-line string, `i` = case insensitive, `s` = dot matches newline

Comment: Have a look at www.phpliveregex.com and www.regex101.com. Those websites help me alot, You can see what happens with your Regex code. And keep in mind, when using regex, you need to put two backslashes in PHP. Because `\/` evaluates to `/` which causes errors. You need to double escape :)

Comment: There is a misconception here. `m` is only relevant when you have `^` or `$` in your pattern.  The `m` can be safely removed.